# Toll free bridges

Tags: objective-c, iphone, macos

As a newcomer to iPhone development and Objective-C in general over the last few weeks I have come across numerous mentions of 'Toll free bridges' between CF and NS frameworks.

One particular example would be CFStream and NSStream.

Does a resource exists documenting all of these bridges and how to use them ? Is it just as simple as casting from an object of one type to another ?

I ask as at the moment I am using NSStream calls that are not stricly allowed within the iPhone SDK and understand that I should be using CFStream calls.

EDIT: A useful article about [how TFB works](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-01-22-toll-free-bridging-internals.html)

Comment: There is an excellent blog post on this subject. Check out http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2006/09/09/bridge/ I was leery of toll-free bridging until I understood it better.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Toll-free bridging means that the data structures are interchangeable. It is just as simple as casting — that's the "toll-free" part. Anyplace you can use the type on one side of the bridge, you can use the other. So, for example, you can create a CFString and then send NSString messages to it, or you can create an NSArray and pass the array to CFArray functions.

Apple keeps a [list of the supported toll-free bridged types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002401-767858) on its site.

Comment: Updated link to [toll-free bridged data types](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002401-767858)

Comment: interesting. they don't list `CFNullRef` and `NSNull`

Comment: @user102008: Yeah, no clue why they seem to be so reluctant to acknowledge those two. They've been bridged since CFNull's introduction AFAIK.

Comment: This answer doesn't cover ARC's bridged casts - an edit to bring it up to date would be cool.

Comment: If these types are interchangeable, why do they exist in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Toll-free-bridging, although a funny name, is a very cool feature of the CoreFoundation classes.  Essentially it boils down to the fact that you can cast between CoreFoundation and NextStep classes of the same name (CFString<->NSString, CFData<->NSData, CFDictionary<->NSDictionary... just to name some of the most commonly used.)

|K<