# Releasing Core Foundation object references

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-foundation

Do I need to release a Core Foundation objects to clear up memory? And if so, how?

For example, in the code:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef peopleArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

do I need to release `peopleArray`? What about `addressBook`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, in CoreFoundation you have to release anything with Create or Copy in the name. You do this with CFRelease(). In your case, you should be releasing both the array and the address book references.

Comment: Thank you. I struggled to find the answer to this on Google. Probably because I was googling for "Core Framework" instead of "Core Foundation". Doh! :)

Answer (score 26):

The [rules](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148) for memory management in Core Foundation are similar to those in Cocoa: if the method that returns a reference contains the words "create" or "copy", you own the reference and must call `CFRelease()` on that reference to relinquish ownership. Otherwise, you do *not* own the reference and must call `CFRetain` to take ownership (necessarily requiring a subsequent `CFRelease` to relinquish that new ownership). These rules, as taken from the Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation are:

- If you create an object (either
  directly or by making a copy of
  another object—see “The Create
  Rule”), you own it.
- If you get an
  object from somewhere else, you do
  not own it. If you want to prevent it
  being disposed of, you must add
  yourself as an owner (using
  CFRetain).
- If you are an owner of an
  object, you must relinquish ownership
  when you have finished using it
  (using CFRelease).

In your example, both the `addressBook` and the `peopleArray` must be released. Since there is no `autorelease` equivalent in Core Foundation, if you are returning the a reference from a method, return the array *without* releasing it. You should (unless you're being evil) then include "create" in the method name to indicate to the caller that they now own a reference to the returned object. In this case, CFArray is toll-free bridged to `NSCFArray`, an Objective-C object that inherits from `NSObject`. You can thus cast `peopleArray` to an `NSArray*` and `autorelease` that, if you need to return it from a function/method:

```
return [(NSArray*)peopleArray autorelease];
```

Note that this only works for toll-free bridged classes. My understanding is that it's rather difficult to make your own toll-free bridged classes and only the primitive (string, array, etc.) CF classes are toll-free bridged, so this approach won't work always. Finally, if you can avoid using `autorelease` (i.e. you can make your memory management more explicit), that's probably always a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Barry - I am well versed in the memory rules of Cocoa - I just wasn't sure if the CF rules were the same. Glad to know that they are.

Comment: The same, except for the lack of autorelease... If you're comfortable with the Cocoa rules and avoid autorelease if possible, you're completely at home.

Comment: Objects that are toll-free bridged may be autoreleased by casting to id: [(id)cfObject autorelease];

Comment: Right, so in this instance, the CFArrayRef could be cast to an NSArray* and autoreleased as in [(NSArray*)peopleArray autorelease]. I'll add that to the answer text.

Comment: So how do you return an object that is not toll-free bridged?

Answer (score 4):

Another small point that no-one has mentioned yet, some CF classes have a "toll-free bridge"  with their NS counterpart. `CFString` and `NSString`, `CFArray` and `NSArray` are both examples. This is relevant as you can just use `release` with these classes.

See this [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806115/toll-free-bridges/806444) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading Apple's [guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html) on Core Foundation memory management for an in-depth discussion of this. They have a similar guide for general Cocoa memory management as well.

To release a CF object, you would call the `CFRelease` function.

Answer (score 3):

For ARC you can use.

```
return (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)peopleArray;
```

"__bridge_transfer" will transfer the ownership to ARC and therefore you don't need any further release call.