# Keyboard in a fullscreen cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, macos

Following up on this ( [Display System Keyboard Mac application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860256/display-system-keyboard-mac-application) ) question, the keyboard is coming up fine, but if my application is in fullscreen mode, the keyboard launches, but remains in the background. How do I get around this? Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Teja

Answer (score 0):

Full screen is, by definition, above other windows and elements. I don't know how well this would work, but you could try asking the view for its -window, then using -setLevel: to lower the window level. Unfortunately, assuming it works at all, this would probably allow other elements (like the dock or other floating panels above your full screen view as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm entering fullscreen using `NSView`'s `enterFullScreenMode: withoptions:`. Apparently you can't change the window level if you enter fullscreen mode using this?