# NSArray turned into NSCFArray upon insertion to dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to save an NSArray as a value in an NSMutableDictionary. When I try to fetch what I've added, it returns an NSFCArray instead of an NSArray:

```
NSArray * list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *name in list) {
    // first attempt
    [dictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:@"test"] forKey:name];
    NSLog(@"first attempt class: %@", [[dictionary valueForKey:name] class]);
    // second attempt
    NSArray * realArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictionary valueForKey:name]];
    NSLog(@"second attempt class: %@", [realArray class]);
}
```

I assume this is being converted for efficiency. However, I need my value returned as an NSArray to call methods like "count" that NSFCArray doesn't have. If I can't store values in a dictionary as an NSArray, how can I convert to a NSArray from a NSFCArray?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSCFArray` == `NSArray`, it's exposing the ["**toll-free bridged**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806115/toll-free-bridges) side of Foundation objects.

You can do everything with an `NSCFArray` as you can with an `NSArray`, and vice versa. You can pass an `NSArray` to a `CFArray` function and you can pass a `CFArray` to an `NSArray` method.

This is because the internal datatype that is known to us as `NSArray` or `CFArray` is *actually* a `NSCFArray`.

This doesn't apply to all Foundation objects, here is a list of all toll-free bridged objects in Cocoa:

[image]

Comment: Ah, now I see count works in my example above. I get a bad access issue elsewhere, but that's another problem. Thanks for the help!